# Moltin Javascript-SDK not working with paypal-pro gateway

Tags: javascript, moltin

I am trying to implement the e-commerce solution, Moltin, on my website but am struggling to get the paypal-pro gateway to work. This is not a NodeJS SDK it is simply a Javascript-SDK. My code looks like this.

```
moltin.Authenticate(function() {

    moltin.Cart.Complete({
      gateway: 'paypal-pro',
      customer: {
        first_name: customer["first_name"],
        last_name:  customer["last_name"],
        email:      customer["email"]
      },
      bill_to: {
        first_name: billto["first_name"],
        last_name:  billto["last_name"],
        address_1:  billto["address_1"],
        city:       billto["city"],
        county:     billto["county"],
        country:    billto["country"],
        postcode:   billto["postcode"]
      },
      ship_to: 'bill_to',
      shipping: 'standard'
    }, function(orders) {
        console.log(orders);
        moltin.Checkout.Payment('purchase', orders.id, {
              data: {
                first_name:   billto["first_name"],
                last_name:    billto["last_name"],
                number:       ccInfo["number"],
                expiry_month: ccInfo["month"],
                expiry_year:  ccInfo["year"],
                cvv:          ccInfo["cvv"]
              }
            }, function(success) {
                alert("Congratulations, products are on their way!");
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
        });

    }, function(error) {
        //Error
    });

});
```

After the code is run, I successfully log an object for the order meaning that the Cart was completed, but I get an error that looks like this:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

The bad request was to this endpoint: 
https://api.molt.in/v1/checkout/payment/purchase/1306137221123801951 where the number at the end is the id of the order.

Any ideas why this won't process payment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Paypal Pro payment gateway within the [dashboard](https://forge.moltin.com/gateway)?

If it's already enabled and your settings have been added would you be able to join the [moltin slack channel](https://moltin.com/community) so we can give you closer support?